# AutoMapper use for simple Entity Properties to SqlParameters array

Tags: c#, automapper

I've begun looking into AutoMapper and have a 'data driven' scenario... I have the code for populating entity properties from a SqlDataReader based on some 'schema information' I pass around...

Next I want to take Entity properties... and then based on the Schema information I have, create a set of SqlParameters from the entity values...

Perfect job for AutoMapper... but I see a lot of flattening from Object graph to Object graph but no simple samples for this task...   When going at it, I've stumbled a bit with some of the nuances but have a rough idea of what I should be doing...

I've drafted up the following... I'm trying to use the TypeConverters and registering them in advance, but when I execute the actual map.ForMember() operation it throws an error complaining

"Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type."

A few variations I have tried and not been successfull with...

(1) tried far simpler versions...
(2) tried using the ConstructUsing() mechanism and then the target of the operation is actually the SqlParameter.[[[Value]]] property (most likely the 'right' way in the AutoMapper mindset right??)
(3) tried pre-establishing the target list and then 'finding' the matching parameter - but setting the .Value on it was still a missing part of that equation...

Being new to AutoMapper I expected a few challenges but I've spent enough time on this and not found anything obvious... seems like it should be a simple use-case for the framework...  I must be missing something obvious...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Drive it by some data... Say some mapping info we have from elsewhere...
        var myMappingPairs = new List<MyMappingInfo>()
        {
            new MyMappingInfo() { PropertyName = "MyGuidProperty", ParameterName = "Param00" },
            new MyMappingInfo() { PropertyName = "MyStringProperty", ParameterName = "Param01" },
            new MyMappingInfo() { PropertyName = "MyInt16Property", ParameterName = "Param02" },
            new MyMappingInfo() { PropertyName = "MyInt32Property", ParameterName = "Param03" },
            new MyMappingInfo() { PropertyName = "MyInt64Property", ParameterName = "Param04" }
        };

        // We can try to register these, but the sytax isn't clear to me yet...
        Mapper.CreateMap<Guid, SqlParameter>().ConvertUsing<GuidToSqlParameterConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<String, SqlParameter>().ConvertUsing<StringToSqlParameterConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Int16, SqlParameter>().ConvertUsing<Int16ToSqlParameterConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Int32, SqlParameter>().ConvertUsing<Int32ToSqlParameterConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Int64, SqlParameter>().ConvertUsing<Int64ToSqlParameterConverter>();

        // Next we'll build our mapping from the "pairings"...
        var map = Mapper.CreateMap<MySourceEntity, List<SqlParameter>>();

        foreach (var mappingPair in myMappingPairs)
        {
            map.ForMember
                (
                    destination => destination,
                    options => options.ResolveUsing<PropertyNameResolver>().FromMember
                        (
                            mappingPair.PropertyName    // <-- Data Driven Property Name...
                        )
                );
        }

        // Create a test entity...
        var entity = new MySourceEntity() 
        {
            MyGuidProperty = Guid.NewGuid(), 
            MyStringProperty = "Hello AutoMapper",
            MyInt16Property = Int16.MaxValue,
            MyInt32Property = Int32.MaxValue,
            MyInt64Property = Int64.MaxValue
        };

        // Map it...
        var values = Mapper.Map<MySourceEntity, object[]>
            (
                entity
            );

    }
}

public class MySourceEntity
{
    public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MyDateTimeProperty { get; set; }
    public Byte? MyByteProperty { get; set; }
    public Int16? MyInt16Property { get; set; }
    public Int32? MyInt32Property { get; set; }
    public Int64? MyInt64Property { get; set; }
    public Guid? MyGuidProperty { get; set; }

    public List<String> ThisShouldntGetMapped { get; set; }
    public StringBuilder NorShouldThis { get; set; }
}

public class MyMappingInfo
{
    public String PropertyName { get; set; }
    public String ParameterName { get; set; }
    public SqlDbType SqlDbType { get; set; }
}

public class GuidToSqlParameterConverter : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<Guid, SqlParameter>
{
    public SqlParameter Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsSourceValueNull)
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "GuidParam",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
                Value = DBNull.Value
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "GuidParam",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,
                Value = context.SourceValue
            };
        }
    }
}
public class StringToSqlParameterConverter : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<string, SqlParameter>
{
    public SqlParameter Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsSourceValueNull)
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "StringParam",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Value = DBNull.Value
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "StringParam",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                Value = context.SourceValue
            };
        }
    }
}

public class Int16ToSqlParameterConverter : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<Int16, SqlParameter>
{
    public SqlParameter Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsSourceValueNull)
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "Int16Param",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt,
                Value = DBNull.Value
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "Int16Param",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallInt,
                Value = context.SourceValue
            };
        }
    }
}

public class Int32ToSqlParameterConverter : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<Int32, SqlParameter>
{
    public SqlParameter Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsSourceValueNull)
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "Int32Param",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Value = DBNull.Value
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "Int32Param",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                Value = context.SourceValue
            };
        }
    }
}

public class Int64ToSqlParameterConverter : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<Int64, SqlParameter>
{
    public SqlParameter Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsSourceValueNull)
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "Int64Param",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt,
                Value = DBNull.Value
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "Int64Param",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt,
                Value = context.SourceValue
            };
        }
    }
}
```

}

I would like to know if the resulting runtime code in AutoMapper will be better performing than say:

```
    static IDictionary<string, object> GetDictionaryFromObject(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        return obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                   .ToDictionary(p => p.Name,
                                 p => p.GetValue(obj, null) ?? DBNull.Value);
    }
```

Which is the entire point of using AutoMapper for me... I already knew how to write reflection code... and I could always have looked at a pure reflection based library to get some additional performance gains, but I thought AutoMapper would likely be a two birds - one stone deal...

Comment: BTW - that last code snipper was from here off SO...

Comment: Code too long. Can you narrow it down?